# Depois que o user faz logout, ele sai, mas se clicar na seta de voltar do navegador ele acessa novamente

Tags: php, laravel

O código de logout [laravel]

```
 public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $guard = $this->getGuard();

    Auth::guard($guard)->logout();

    $request->session()->flush();

    return redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: E se voltar e atualizar, o que acontece?

Comment: Ele volta pra tela de login, mas o ruim é se o user deixar a tela aberta e alguém voltar pra ver algum dado

Comment: Isso é estranho, você está usando o middleware de auth na sua rota ou no `__construct` do seu controller?

Comment: Tá sendo usado nos dois, tanto na rota como no controller.

Comment: Eu li algo que diz que quando você clica em voltar, não necessariamente o navegador está fazendo um novo request, ele pode estar pegando o estado da página anterior e apenas exibindo.MAS nenhuma solução

Comment: Exatamente. A página anterior já está em memória, não precisa fazer uma nova requisição para exibí-la.

Comment: Você pode dar uma lida nessa [explicação](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30119257/1276269) E se mesmo assim quiser tentar algo, você pode tentar [essa solução](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42057397/1276269)

Comment: tranquilo, vlw pela ajuda ai

Answer (score 0):

Esse redirecionamento procurará uma propriedade de sessão específica que foi definida anteriormente pelo primeiro exemplo de código. Se por algum motivo os dados da sessão estiverem faltando, você pode passar um URL de redirecionamento padrão como parâmetro:

return redirect()->intended('paginaLogin');

Lembrando: tem que proteger as rotas para funcionar

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Seu código ta certo, mas no loginController você precisa validar se existe autenticação, como você destruiu ele não vai está logado usando o `Auth::check()` você valida se ele ta logado ou não.

Answer (score -2):

No login podes fazer um `session_name('nomedasessaoaescolha')`, dares inicio de sessão `session_start()` e guardares numa variável de sessão os dados do user por ex: `$_SESSION['user'] = $row['id']` e `$_SESSION['nome'] = $row['nome']`.

No logout necessitas de fazer um `session_unset("nomedasessaoacimaescolhido")` e necessitas de destruir a sessão `session_destroy()`.

Depois nas outras páginas todas onde não pretendes que acedam após logout é só colocar o seguinte pedaço de código:

```
session_name('nomesessao');

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user'] != ""){


}else{

  header('Location: index.html');

}
```

Comment: E como isso resolve o problema de pressionar o Voltar do navegador e visualizar uma página em cache?

Comment: Tal como referi no 3º parágrafo onde for colocado aquele pedaço de código, ao pressionar o Voltar vai verificar se o utilizador está logado, caso não esteja vai redirecioná-lo para a página login por ex.

Comment: A questão é que esse código só é executado se houver uma nova requisição ao servidor, o que não acontece quando é pressionado o voltar.

Comment: Como uma nova requisição ao servidor? Se o código está localizado no header de todas as páginas que não permitam acesso sem ter login feito.

Comment: Ao pressionar voltar, o navegador irá exibir a versão em cache da página, assim o código do servidor não será executado novamente. Como a página anterior o usuário possuía o login, a página em cache será também com o login; a verificação se a sessão existe ou não não será executada. Só será executada quando o usuário tentar efetuar alguma ação que faz uma requisição ao servidor. Isso é "problema" de cache, não de gerenciamento de sessão.

Comment: Certo já percebi o problema, existe é um pequeno erro na afirmação, porque a página anterior possuia sim ainda o login, mas esse mesmo login é destruido no logout (session_destroy) o que fará com que a tal página anterior referida que tinha login já não o possua e assim com a validação acima mencionada já não permita o acesso à página.

Comment: Não, porque a verificação acima **não será executada** quando pressionar o voltar. Leia sobre o que é cache e faça o teste para entender melhor.